# Broadcasting an UDP packet from an Android app and detecting it from Node.js

Tags: android, node.js, sockets, networking

My Android app needs to know the ip of the machine running the server on my local network. My plan is to broadcast an UDP packet in my app and to send a packet back from the server, so the app know the ip.

This is my code on Android:

```
...

new SendUDPTask().execute();

...

/************ getBroadcastAddress: know where to send the signal to find the server ***********/

private InetAddress getBroadcastAddress() {

    //setup
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    DhcpInfo dhcp = wifiManager.getDhcpInfo();

    //complicated stuff
    int broadcast = (dhcp.ipAddress & dhcp.netmask) | ~dhcp.netmask;
    byte[] quads = new byte[4];
    for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
        quads[k] = (byte) ((broadcast >> k * 8) & 0xFF);

    //return result
    InetAddress result = null;
    try {

        result = InetAddress.getByAddress(quads);

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    return result;

}

/************ sendUDP: here e send the packet that will allow us to find the server ***********/

private DatagramPacket sendUDP(String req, int port) throws IOException {

    DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(port);
    socket.setBroadcast(true);

    InetAddress broadcastAddress = getBroadcastAddress();
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(req.getBytes(), req.length(), broadcastAddress, port);
    socket.send(packet);

    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
    socket.setSoTimeout(3000);

    //We wouldn't want to think our own message is the server's response
    String myAddress = getMyAddress();
    socket.receive(packet);
    while (packet.getAddress().getHostAddress().contains(
            myAddress))
    {
        socket.receive(packet);
    }

    socket.close();

    return packet;
}

/***************************** getMyAddress: the device's address *****************************/

public String getMyAddress() {

    try {

        for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {

            NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();

            for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {

                InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();

                if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress())
                    return inetAddress.getHostAddress();

            }

        }

    }
    catch (SocketException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    return null;
}

private class SendUDPTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, DatagramPacket> {

    private Exception exception;

    protected DatagramPacket doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            DatagramPacket packet = sendUDP("Ping", 31415);
            Log.d("GJ", packet.getAddress().getHostAddress().toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(DatagramPacket packet) {

    }
}
```

This is my code on my computer (Node.js):

```
var PORT = 31415;
var HOST = '127.0.0.1';

var dgram = require('dgram');
var server = dgram.createSocket('udp4');

server.on('listening', function () {
  var address = server.address();
  console.log('UDP Server listening on ' + address.address + ':' + address.port);
});

server.on('message', function (message, remote) {
  console.log(remote.address + ':' + remote.port + ' - ' + message);
});

server.bind(PORT, HOST);
```

I am not sending back anything yet, but I should see the `console.log`. I don't see anything, which must mean the packet didn't arrive.

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you bind the socket to loopback (127.0.0.1) interface you won't receive messages broadcasted in the network (192.168.1.255 in this case). In the nodejs server bind the socket to INADDR_ANY.

Comment: I changed `server.bind(PORT, HOST);` to `server.bind(PORT);`. You're the best

Comment: Hmm. It worked twice and now it doesn't. I tried changing the port to 33333 but that didn't help

Comment: @Gejii, This should be a different problem. I don't believe it is in the nodejs agent. If you run Wireshark on the nodejs side you will be able to see if there is udp arriving to that node. I suppose it is not arriving to that node but ...

Comment: It's not arriving, I guess my router doesn't like me broadcasting. I ended up looping through all the ips in my local subnet

Comment: @Gejii, I wouldn't do that as it may conflict with the problem you want to solve. If you have a group where you don't know who joins or leaves, for example, you'll never know all IP addresses beforehand. Why don't you send a multicast? I think the access point blocks broadcasting but not multicasting.